# scroll bars showing before max-height is reached

Tags: html, css, sass

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e9EmH/2/)**

I've got a problem where I have a container that has a `max-height` set, however for an unknown reason the wrapper constantly shows the vertical scroll bar.

The only thing I can find that might be the problem is the `:after` pseudo class on the `.right` class. If I remove this the scroll bars go. Why is this? The `:after` content is positioned absolutely, it shouldn't have any affect on the scroll bar...

For reference, the `max-height` that's not being reached is set on the `.emails` class

This is the CSS that matters - couple of extra bits on the fiddle;

```
.indicator_triangle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -24px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 12.5px 20px 12.5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
.comm_dd {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    border: 3px solid $green;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 3px solid $green;
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 12px;
    .e_container {
        .emails {
            overflow-y: auto;
            // min-height: 180px;
            max-height: 350px;
            border-top: 1px solid $grey_med;
        }
        h4 {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 5px
        }
        p {
            color: #888;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }
    }
    .left {
        width: 72%;
        float: left;
        div {
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
    }
    .right {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        font-size: 11px;
        &:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 14px;
            right: 4px;
            content:"\00b0";
            font-size: 32px;
        }
    }
    .subj {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    li {
        line-height: 16px;
        a {
            position: relative;
            padding: 6px 5px;
            display: block;
            color: $grey;
            border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
            color: #888;
            padding: 7px 5px;
            &:hover {
                background-color: darken(#fff, 10%);
            }
        }
        .remaining_count {
            top: 9px;
            right: 9px;
        }
        &:first-child a {
            border-top: none;
        }
    }
    .indicator_triangle {
        top: -15px;
        left: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set overflow:hidden to the .comm_dd li selector

Comment: @athms feel free to give that as an answer - it works! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set overflow:hidden to the .comm_dd li selector to prevent the :after pseudo content from causing the overflow on the list item.